# Focus on selected container with blured background

Tags: css

I'm trying to create a step-by-step tutorial and I need to separate container and blur the rest of app. Problem is to create a blurred background without impact on the selected container.

*Selected Container* has given in advance sizes and `position: relative;`. 
I menage to select this container by giving a child component:
 `position: absolute;`
and sizes
 `width: 100%` 
`height: 100%;`, but I can't figure out how to add to the mix a wrapping background `background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)` without an impact on the container.

```
<div style="position: relative; ..." > //Selected container
  <div style="position: absolute; width: 100%; heith: 100%; ..."> // selector
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please add a full code example or create a codesandbox example.

Comment: @LeonVuković here is an example sandbox:
https://codesandbox.io/s/clever-villani-42ycw?file=/src/styles.css
I want to add background/shadow wrapping around of green box (class=selector) and by of a size of the whole app window and be able to see clearly inside of the red container (class=mainContainer).

Comment: I'm not sure that I understand what you want. You want to add shadow to the green box, right? And what do you want to do with the red container?

Comment: I want to focus user sight on red box making overlay on this component which dimming background (making background around component).

Comment: I would like to help you but I still don't get it very well... Do you want to have a background on the whole page and not on the red box element? Image of required design would help me understand (you can draw it in paint and paste here...).

Comment: Yes, exactly, I want a background on the whole page and not on the red box element!

Comment: Check my posted answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a background to your `body` or a wrapper if you have one and then add background to your element because it doesn't have background by default and it will be colored also if you don't specify the background:

```
body {
  background: red; 
}

.mainContainer {
  background: #fff;
}
```